# How to sum multiple hour : mins in sql?

Tags: sql, date, sum, sql-date-functions

i need to sum this varchar values.

```
time 1 = '13:06' 
time 2 = '18:59'
time 3 = '14:49'
```

i tryed this.

```
 SELECT
   convert(
    char(8),
    dateadd(
      second,
      SUM(
       DATEPART(
         hh,
         (convert(datetime,'12:03',1))
       )
       *
       3600
       +
       DATEPART(
         mi,
         (convert(datetime,'13:03',1))
       )
       *
       60
       +
       DATEPART(
         ss,
         (convert(datetime,'34:03',1))
       )
     ),
     0
   ),
   108
 )
 As Total
```

i got Error.

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Could you please first explain the desired result.If we add 13:56 to 14:49 what should we get?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Several product specific functions are used above.)

Comment: Exactly what `DATETIME` do you expect this to give?  `convert(datetime,'34:03',1)`, there is no such time...

Comment: Looks like you should parse the input stings, compute total minutes using int arithmetic (or intervals, depending on DBMS) and format a result as a string you want  in your code as the input doesn't represent values allowed by datetime time or timestamp data types.

Comment: I would like to sum the three value as a time. time 1,time 2 and time3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select the time which was you need to sum as hour min:

```
CAST(sum(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, time)) / 60 AS VARCHAR(8)) + ':' + FORMAT(sum(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, time)) % 60, 'D2') AS [Totalhour]
```